# how to connect these variables with this choice resulted errorlevel

Tags: batch-file

I have a directory `%appdata%\lootbot\locations` where there might be any number of files, each of which contain a single directory path. this code creates a list of those (unknown) files and the paths within and a choice prompt, along with a number to be used by `choice` for selecting them.

```
set "count=0"
for %%s in ("%appdata%\lootbot\locations\*") do set /p locale=<"%%~s" & set "dirname=%%~s" & call :recall
set "choices="
if defined string1 echo %string1% & set "choices=1"
if defined string2 echo %string2% & set "choices=12"
if defined string3 echo %string3% & set "choices=123"
if defined string4 echo %string4% & set "choices=1234"
if defined string5 echo %string5% & set "choices=12345"
if defined string6 echo %string6% & set "choices=123456"
if defined string7 echo %string7% & set "choices=1234567"
if defined string8 echo %string8% & set "choices=12345678"
if defined string9 echo %string9% & set "choices=123456789"
if not defined choices echo too many & pause & exit /b
choice /c %choices%q /n /m "select the saved directory number you want to re-enter or Q to quit: "
echo errorlevel %errorlevel%
exit /b

:recall
set /a "count+=1"
set "string%count%=%count%: %dirname% (%locale%)"
```

the problem is that I can't figure out how to proceed after the choice prompt. I have the `errorlevel` but I need to connect that to the correct `%dirname%` so I can proceed. all my ideas come down to putting variables within variables, resulting in too many `%`... I can't wrap my mind around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid I don't really understand what is your request... However, perhaps this code may help you:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

. . .

set "choices= 123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW" & rem Max = 32

set "count=0"
for %%s in ("%appdata%\lootbot\locations\*") do (
   set /A count+=1
   if !count! gtr 32 echo Too many & pause & exit /B
   for /F %%c in ("!count!") do (
      set /P "locale[%%c]=" < "%%s"
      set "dirname[%%c]=%%~s"
      echo !choices:~%%c,1!: !dirname[%%c]! (!locale[%%c]!^)
   )
)

choice /c !choices:~1,%count%!X /n /m "select the saved directory you want to re-enter or X to eXit: "
echo errorlevel: %errorlevel%
echo Selected dirname: !dirname[%errorlevel%]!
echo Selected locale:  !locale[%errorlevel%]!
```

I suggest you to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990).

Comment: good stuff. I'm trying to figure out how to use the `X` for exit. because the variable is the last one the errorlevel number varies. putting it in the front would mess up the numbering.

Answer (score 1):

```
call :locations

rem Too many files causes error.
if errorlevel 1 exit /b 1

rem Probably no files if choices is undefined.
if not defined choices exit /b 2

choice /c %choices%q /n /m "select the saved directory number you want to re-enter or Q to quit: "
call :locations %errorlevel%

rem Probably entered q if dirname is undefined.
if not defined dirname exit /b 0

echo dirname is "%dirname%".
echo locale is "%locale%".
exit /b

:locations
setlocal
set "count=0"
set "chosen=%~1"

if not defined chosen (
    rem Display menu and set choices.

    for %%s in ("%appdata%\lootbot\locations\*") do (
        set /a "count+=1"
        set /p locale=<"%%~s"
        call echo %%count%%: %%~s (%%locale%%^)
        call set "choices=%%choices%%%%count%%"
    )

    set "locale="
) else (
    rem Set dirname and locale.

    for %%s in ("%appdata%\lootbot\locations\*") do (
        set /a "count+=1"

        @rem If current is 0, then replace 0 with nothing makes current undefined.
        set /a "current=chosen-count"
        call set "current=%%current:0=%%"

        if not defined current (
            set /p locale=<"%%~s"
            set "dirname=%%~s"
        )
    )
)

if %count% gtr 9 exit /b 1

rem Set nonlocal variables.
endlocal & (
    set "choices=%choices%"
    set "dirname=%dirname%"
    set "locale=%locale%"
)
exit /b
```

`call :locations` with no arguments will set `chosen`
to undefined which executes the 1st `for` loop to
display the menu. `choices` will be `set` with the
string of integers to be used with the `choice` command.

`call :locations %errorlevel%` will set `chosen` to the
value of the argument. The 2nd `for` loop is executed.
If `chosen` is the same value of `count`,
then `current` will be set to `0` as the number minus the
same number equals zero. If zero is replaced with zero,
then current is undefined, which flags for setting
`dirname` and `locale`.

At the end of the `call`, `choices`, `dirname` and `locale`
will be set in nonlocal scope.

`dirname` and `locale` will be echoed at end of the script
to display the result.